# How to validate a document against Elasticsearch mapping without indexing it in Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mapping, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-py

I'm working with Elasticsearch in Python and I have a scenario where I want to validate a document against an existing index's mapping before actually sending it for indexing. The goal is to ensure that the document adheres to the expected field types and constraints defined in the mapping.

For example, given the following mapping for a customized index:

```json
"mappings": {
 "properties": {
  "title": { "type": "text" },
  "publish_date": { "type": "date" },
  "views": { "type": "integer"}
 }
}
```

I want to validate documents like:

```json
{
"title": "Sample Article",
"publish_date": "2023-10-05",
"views": 1234
}
```

And get feedback if, for instance, views was mistakenly a string instead of an integer.

I'm aware that I could write custom validation logic to achieve this, but I'm looking for a more streamlined solution, possibly a library or tool that can handle this out of the box.

Has anyone come across a Python library or tool that offers this functionality? Or is there a recommended approach to achieve this without manually parsing the mapping and validating each field?

Comment: With the additional difficulty that sending `"1234"` or `1234` will both get accepted for an integer field because type coercion kicks in (but that can be disabled)

Comment: What should happen if the document does not adhere to the mapping and can't be validated?

Comment: @Val How could it not be validated? In your example, leaving elasticsearch's rules aside, pythonically this can be validated

Comment: I don't follow... if some value doesn't adhere to the mapping for some reason, what do you do? If you want to validate your data, it's because you think there's a slight chance that it doesn't adhere to the mapping, right?

Comment: true, i want to handle it properly without guessing which field is at fault

Comment: Back to my question, what should happen if for some reason a document can't be validated because some value doesn't adhere to the expected mapping? say `views` contains `"None"` for some reason. What do you do?

Comment: if a document doesn't adhere to the expected mapping, I'd like to:

Identify which specific field or fields caused the validation to fail.
Return or log a clear error message indicating the issue.
Optionally, prevent the document from being indexed until the issue is resolved.
The goal is to have a proactive approach to data quality, ensuring that only valid documents get indexed and any anomalies are caught and addressed early on.

Comment: That's what I wanted to see: `Return or log a clear error message indicating the issue`. if you let ES do the job for you, you'll get exactly that: a clear message and nothing gets indexed. Additionally, you don't have to maintain the same rules in two places: in your mapping + in your validation code

Comment: My main concern was to catch potential issues before making a call to Elasticsearch, to reduce unnecessary network traffic or to handle validation in a specific manner within my application.

Comment: If you are in control of the code that generates your data and you've tested it properly, that should not be a concern.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. While having control over the data generation process and thorough testing are crucial, there are scenarios or edge cases in complex systems where unexpected data anomalies can occur. I'm aiming for an additional layer of validation as a safeguard to ensure data quality and consistency. It's more about being proactive and having a failsafe in place

Comment: You might be looking for something like this where your index mapping creation is driven by your Python validation code: https://dzone.com/articles/pydantic-and-elasticsearch-dynamic-couple

Comment: Not bad at all, if you post this as an answer i will accept it. (and upvote of course:)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to have to manage your index mapping in Elasticsearch on one side and "copy/paste" the same rules in your Python code on the other side. That's doomed to failure over the long term!

You might be looking for something like [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest) ([intro article](https://dzone.com/articles/pydantic-and-elasticsearch-dynamic-couple)) which allows you to drive your index mapping creation directly from your Python code validation rules.

Comment: fantastic answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helps!